# targetting just one image under a div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to show a different image based on a random number. If the number is not two I want to change the image to `box-lose` on the box that the user clicked on.

Unfortunately, I am not able to target this image. I want to change just the image that the user clicked on to the lose image. [see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ftynfL7f/2/) which may make the question clearer. I have tried to use `closest` and `find` however I cannot seem to target the element.

**js**

```
$('.box').click(function(){

    var randomNumber = 1;
    var thisBox = $(this);

    if(randomNumber === 2){
       alert('number is 2');
   } else {                 
       thisBox.closest('img').find('.box-img').css('display', 'none');
       thisBox.closest('img').find('.box-lose').css('display', 'block');
   }
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="box">
   <img class="box-img" src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.986006.1336765559!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/gallery_1200/hulk-hogan-pastamania.jpg">
   <img class="box-win" src="http://www.profightdb.com/img/wrestlers/thumbs-600/1414330df8brethart.jpg">
   <img class="box-lose" src="http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2014-12-11-Hulk.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img class="box-img" src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.986006.1336765559!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/gallery_1200/hulk-hogan-pastamania.jpg">
  <img class="box-win" src="http://www.profightdb.com/img/wrestlers/thumbs-600/1414330df8brethart.jpg">
  <img class="box-lose" src="http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2014-12-11-Hulk.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img class="box-img" src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.986006.1336765559!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/gallery_1200/hulk-hogan-pastamania.jpg">
  <img class="box-win" src="http://www.profightdb.com/img/wrestlers/thumbs-600/1414330df8brethart.jpg">
  <img class="box-lose" src="http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2014-12-11-Hulk.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: where you are generating `random` number?

Comment: No need to use `closest` here. `closest` will find the closest parent that matches the given selector. `.box` has no parent that matches `img`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am just using that for the purpose of the question. It is irrelevant really. I am concerned with changing just one image in the `if/else` statement.

Comment: @J.Titus ah got it, just had to remove `closest`

Comment: Fixed your JSFiddle in the post, it didn't even run because of syntax error and missing jQuery. And the reason you had to remove `closest` is because `find` searches in *children* of the selected elements, and what you want is to search *among* the selected elements (which is done using `filter`). By removing `closest`, you are now searching in children of the `div.box` and not the `img`s, which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a coinflip for win and lose and to display a certain picture on the result you would just create a random number and define a context for your selectors. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftynfL7f/6/)

You should avoid using functions such as `.closest()`. There are always better options.

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    $('.box-img', $(this)).hide();
  if (randomNumber === 2) {
    $('.box-win', $(this)).show();
  } else {
    $('.box-lose', $(this)).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`Updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ftynfL7f/5/)

I think `click` event was not firing when I used in first instance. So I just made use of `.on` - `click` and then wrapped the code within `$(function()` aka `$(document).ready`. Also, you don't need to use **[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**, as it will search through linked elements and their ancestors in the `DOM` tree. Below is the updated code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        var thisBox = $(this);
        if (randomNumber === 2) {
            alert('number is 2');
        } else {
            thisBox.find('.box-img').css('display', 'none');
            thisBox.find('.box-lose').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```